# Escolher uma lista usando a função input

Tags: python-3.x

Tenho duas ou mais listas e quero permitir que o usuário escolha qual delas deseja imprimir:

```
L=[2,4]
M=[6,8]

x=input('Escolha a lista "L" ou "M":')

for j in x:
    print(j)
```

Este código não funciona. Retorna L ou M.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Analise esse código: https://ideone.com/0eoacb

Answer (score -2):

Eu te respondo se você prometer que não vai usar. Definir o nome da variável dinamicamente é muito perigoso. Use dicionário.  A resposta está baixo:

```
L = [2,4] 
M = [6,8] 
x=input('Escolha a lista "L" ou "M":')  // isso retorna um string 
print(vars()[x])
```

Comment: Obrigada, Leo. Funcionou.